# How to identify / list all of the GITHUB webhooks (URL) using Python?

Tags: python, url, github, python-requests, webhooks

I am working with the requests and Github python libraries, basically to build a script to update the webhooks (URL) in github, under certains conditions.

Using the following code, I get some info like GitHub organization, GitHub user and GitHub repositories (just to give some examples):

```
**from github import Github
import json
import requests
def function_example():
    gh = Github('MY_TOKEN_HERE', base_url='https://MY-GITHUB-DOMAIN/api/v3')
    get_users = gh.get_user().name
    print("USERNAME: ", get_users)
    print(" ")
    # user_repos = gh.repos.list().all()
    user_repos = gh.get_repos()
    print("REPOS: ", user_repos)
    print(" ")
    orgs = gh.get_organization('MY_GITHUB_ORG_HERE')
    print("ORGS: ", orgs)
    print(" ")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_example()
# Eof**
```

However, I need to identify the webhooks URL (located in Github -> Repo -> Setting -> Webhooks), in order to update them with a new domain. The problem is that I haven't found how to get or list all of the webhooks for an specific repository.

I have been reading about a Licenced library called [smartsheet](https://developers.smartsheet.com/), and it looks like that using that library
we could handler the webhooks... but I don't have that library installed here :-(

Is it possible to list / identify the URL webhooks, using those python libraries (requests and/or Github) ?

If so, could somebody send me an example ?

I will be really thankful of that !

Jose

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a Github Webhooks API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#list-hooks

Using requests, you ought to be able to perform CRUD operations on the webhooks for each of your repos.

The call to list a repo's hooks would look something like this:

```
import requests
token = "YOUR_OAUTH_OR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
repo = "connect4"
user = "dreslan"
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/hooks".format(user, repo)
headers = {"Authorization": "token {}".format(token)}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# r.content will display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the `GetHooks()` call.  See https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Comment: Hi Ywapom,

Thanks for your reply.
I forgot to say that I had already used those REST API commands and arguments (basically the curl tool). My problem is that I haven't be able to translate those commands into Python sentences (using the requests and Github libraries or other)....

As you can see in the python code I sent before, actually I get information about Orgs, Repo and the Username. However I need to list (identify) and update the webhooks (url) through python code...If you have any other info, pls, let me know.
I am going to take a look to the @Dreslan response..
thanks a lot!